Subtract datetime in R they are currently in the Character class
I have two columns in the df named alldf one is started_at and the other ended_at.
"2020-04-19 07:59:05" 

The class is in the character format, and I need to subtract ended_at - started_at.
I tried the following.
as.Date(alldf$started_at,'%Y-%m-%d')
as.Date(alldf$started_at,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
alldf$ended_year <- as.integer(alldf$ended_year)

All of them comes with NA for %H:%M:%S
Any help is very welcome.

When posting to SO provide a complete reproducible example code such that if others run it they will see the problem.
Below we show the difference in seconds and in days which in this case is 0 regardless.  See ?difftime for more information.
ct1 <- as.POSIXct("2020-04-19 07:59:05")
ct2 <- as.POSIXct("2020-04-19 07:59:05")

as.double(ct1 - ct2, units = "secs")
## [1] 0

as.double(ct1 - ct2, units = "days")
## [1] 0


When I enter the code below.    as.POSIXct(alldf$started_at, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M") , it returns all results as NA.

If your data is in the format shown in the question then the format in your comment does not correspond.  The format shown is the default so omit format= .  If the format is something else that you have not shown then the format= would have to correspond to whatever it is.
